# Can I overload operators on enum types in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, enums

For example, if I have:

```
typedef enum { year, month, day } field_type;

inline foo operator *(field_type t,int x)
{
   return foo(f,x);
}
inline foo operator -(field_type t)
{
   return t*-1;
}
int operator /(distance const &d,field_type v)
{
  return d.in(v);
}
```

Because if I do not define such operators it is actually legal to write `day*3` and it
would be translated into 6?

So is it legal?

At least gcc and intel compiler accept this without a warning.

**Clearification:**

I do not want default arithmetic operations, I want my own operations that return non-integer type.

Comment: What is that `foo` type?

Comment: foo is some complex data structure for example `struct foo { field_type type, int value; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, operator overloading can be done on enum and class types. The way you do it is fine, but you should use `+` to promote the enumeration, instead of `*-1` or something (the purpose ultimately is to avoid infinite recursion because `-t`):

```
inline foo operator -(field_type t) {
   return -+t;
}
```

This will scale well to other operations. `+` will promote the enumeration to an integer type that can represent its value, and then you can apply `-` without causing infinite recursion.

---

Notice that your `operator*` does only allow you to do `enum_type * integer`, but not the other way around. It may be worth considering the other direction too.

Also notice that it's always a bit dangerous to overload operators for operands that builtin-operators already accept (even if only by implicit conversions). Imagine that `distance` has a converting constructor taking int (as in `distance(int)`), then given your `operator/` the following is ambiguous

```
// ambiguous: operator/(int, int) (built-in) or
//            operator/(distance const&, field_type) ?
31 / month;
```

For this, maybe it's better to make `field_type` a real class with the appropriate operators, so that you can exclude any of such implicit conversions from begin on. Another good solution is provided by C++0x's `enum class`, which provides strong enumerations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking is this code legal:

```
enum A {
    x,y
};

int main() {
    int z = x * y;
}
```

The answer is unfortunately "yes". There is an implicit conversion from enum values to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is legal. ENUM will automatically turns values into INT.

Comment: that is exactly I do not want. I ask is it legal to overload?

Comment: @Artyom: Wrong. You explictly asked "If I **do not define** such operators it is actually legal to write `day*3` and it would be translated into `6`?". This apparently is the answer to *that* question of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer to your question about `day * 3` is: yes, you can do it. You don't need any operator overloading for that. And the result will be `6`. However, this will work by converting your `day` constant to `int` type, performing multiplication within the `int` type and giving the result of type `int`, i.e. that `6` is an `int`. Which rises the next question: Are you OK with it being an `int`? What are you planning to do with that `6` afterwards? If an `int` is OK for your purpose, then you don't need to do anything.

However, it is possible that you actually want to obtain the result of `field_type` type from `day * 3`. You see, in C++ `int` type is not explicitly convertible to enum types. So this will compile and work

```
int product = day * 3;
```

but this will not

```
field_type product = day * 3; // ERROR
```

You can force the latter to compile by using an explicit cast

```
field_type product = (field_type) (day * 3);
```

or you can start playing with operator overloading, like

```
field_type operator *(field_type lhs, int rhs)
{
  return (field_type) ((int) lhs * rhs)
}
```

Note, that the implementation of the overloaded operator still relies on a cast, so this is just a way to make the "main" code of your program look cleaner, by encapsulating the ugly casts into dedicated operators (nothing's wrong with it).

As a pedantic side note, I'd like to add that there are certain formal dangers in trying to squeeze the results of integer arithmetic operations into a enum type (if that's what you want; maybe you don't, since you seem to be using some other type `foo` for the result providing no details about it). The range of values a enum object can represent is [roughly] determined by the maximum (by magnitude) value of enum constant rounded to the next highest (by magnitude) number of the form `2^N-1`. In your case the highest value is `day` equal to 2, which means that your enum is guaranteed to represent values up to `3` accurately. If you try to convert `6` to your enum type the result is unspecified (although it will normally work "as expected" in practice).

Comment: "since you seem to be using some other type foo" indeed I just not mentioned it is just a simple class that hold both enum and off set so I can write `date+=year*3+month*3+week` where some type would hold the full offsets.

Comment: Your `operator*` implementation will end up in endless recursion