# Overloaded operator not working in method

Tags: c++, methods, operator-keyword

I have to make a program calculating on my new type of symbols and I have encountered a problem I cannot solve.

Code piece:

```
typedef struct{
  Symbol a1, a2, w_wcz, w_ok; 
  char oper, rown;     

  int Oblicz(){ 
  if(rown != '='){
    cerr << "Blad, brak symbolu rownosci!" << endl;
    return 0;}
  switch(oper){
  case '+':
    w_ok=a1+a2;

  case '-':
    w_ok=a1-a2

  case '*':
    w_ok=a1*a2;

  case '/':
    w_ok=a1/a2;       

  default:
    cerr << "Blad, nieznany operator!" << endl; 
    return 0;}

  }
}WyrAlg;
```

a,b,c,d,e are of enum Symbol type.
+, -, * and / operators are overloaded for two symbols and are working fine, it's only getting problematic when I try to put it in method.

In main I have

```
WyrAlg Wyr;
[it is initialized here with values]
Wyr.Oblicz();
```

And what I'm getting is:

```
[tjakubo2@diablo:~/kpo/lab04]$ make
g++ -pedantic -Wall -o dzialok.out dzialaniamod.cpp
dzialaniamod.cpp: In member function 'int<anonymous struct>::Oblicz()':
dzialaniamod.cpp:32:8: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Symbol' [-fpermissive]
     w_ok=a1+a2;
            ^     
dzialaniamod.cpp:40:12: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Symbol' [-fpermissive]
     w_ok=a1-a2;
            ^
dzialaniamod.cpp:48:12: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Symbol' [-fpermissive]
     w_ok=a1*a2;
            ^
dzialaniamod.cpp:56:12: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Symbol' [-fpermissive]
     w_ok=a1/a2;
            ^
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `dzialok.out'
```

And I can't figure what going on, need help on this. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Including overloaded operator:
(may be unclear but it works fine)

```
enum Symbol {e,a,b,c,d};
Symbol tab_dod[5][5]= {{e,a,b,c,d},{a,b,c,d,e},{b,c,d,e,a},{c,d,e,a,b},{d,e,a,b,c}};

Symbol operator + (Symbol x, Symbol y){

   return tab_dod[x][y];
}
```

CLARIFICATION EDIT 2:
Function-version of that is working ok, Ill paste it here if you need it:
The only difference is that w_ok is outside WyrAlg, insted it is only in function:

```
int ObliczWyr(WyrAlg Wyr){
  Symbol w_ok;
  if(Wyr.rown != '='){
    cerr << "Blad, brak symbolu rownosci!" << endl;
    return 0;}
  switch(Wyr.oper){
  case '+':
    w_ok=Wyr.a1+Wyr.a2;
   [stuff]
      return 2;}
  case '-':
    w_ok=Wyr.a1-Wyr.a2;
  [stuff]
      return 2;}
  case '*':
    w_ok=Wyr.a1*Wyr.a2;
   [stuff] 
      return 4;}
  case '/':
    w_ok=Wyr.a1/Wyr.a2;
    [stuff]
      return 4;}
  default:
    cerr << "Blad, nieznany operator!" << endl; // jesli nieznany operator
    return 0;}

}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your sample to make it minimal while reproducing the error? You can see the error is on line 32, only I can't where line 32 is and I wouldn't look for errors among all those strange names and messages.

Comment: consider adding a stripped down version of "Symbol" as well

Comment: Edited to make it more clear, added example overload (they are working OK)
wonko, what did you mean I should include?

Comment: 1st of all: Please don't use c-like `typedef struct` syntax for c++ code. Besides it's ugly, it's a frequent source of confusion.

Comment: 1.  You might want to add `break;` at the end of every case.  2. The compiler is suggesting that `Symbol operator+` may have another overload returning type `int`.

Comment: You will need to add casting back to Symbol, read here for more : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393439/can-i-overload-operators-on-enum-types-in-c

Comment: The Polish error messages seem more expressive than English!

Comment: wallyk - I stripped most of the cases to just show what's important, there is quite lot of stuff and return on the end of each :)
And I have no idea why it says anything about in, a1 an a2 are clearly of type symbol and I have an overload for those.
marcin_j: My ovearload functions are working, I can't find anything in that thread :P

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you define the operator overloads before the struct? It seems that the compiler tries to convert `Symbol` enum to `int`, and then apply `int operator+(int, int)` on them. Maybe you could try C++11 enum class to make sure it's not a problem of implicit conversions from enums to int?

Comment: I get your exact error when I don't declare the operator before I call it...is your operator declared in the same header as Symbol? Is Symbol defined anywhere else? Do you have a define guard problem?

Comment: I suggest removing `typedef` and placing the `typedef` name after the word `struct`.  This will make the compiler use the structure name in the error messages instead of *anonymous struct*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is compiled successfully

```
#include <iostream>

enum Symbol {e,a,b,c,d};
Symbol tab_dod[5][5]= {{e,a,b,c,d},{a,b,c,d,e},{b,c,d,e,a},{c,d,e,a,b},{d,e,a,b,c}};

Symbol operator + (Symbol x, Symbol y)
{
    return tab_dod[x][y];
}

int main()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        Symbol a1, a2, w_wcz, w_ok; 
        char oper, rown;     

        int Oblicz()
        { 
            switch(oper)
            {
                case '+':
                    w_ok=a1+a2;
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cerr << "Blad, nieznany operator!" << std::endl; 
                    break;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    } WyrAlg;

    WyrAlg alg;
    alg.a1 = e;
    alg.a2 = a;
    alg.oper = '+';
    alg.Oblicz();
}
```

Maybe you declared the operator after the structure definition.

Comment: Rewrote, sorted out, working. I dont know what was causing it, while tring to make it work one of the first things I did was putting + operator overload before everything and still got the error at + operation. Probably messed up something by the way or I'm just stupid. Thanks anyways!